# update query for more than one thing

Tags: mysql

Update the S_Loc, S_Code that has the lowest value.

I keep getting error 
error code: 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's on library.S_Code = s.S_Code

```
Update library 
inner join (
    Select S_Code 
    from Book 
    group by S_Code 
    having count(xy) = min(count(xy)) s 
on Book.S_Code = s.S_Code 
set S_Loc = 'CB-3322';
```

it changes values with s_code that repeat the least, to have a new s_loc.

Comment: Why are you tagging with MySQL and SSMS? MySQL is an Oracle database product, and SSMS is specifically for Microsoft SQL Server (it's **SQL Server Management Studio**). You're either not using MySQL or not using SSMS. Please [edit] your post and include **only** relevant tags, to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: The error messages look like SQL Server, not MySQL. But the query uses MySQL syntax.

Comment: You can't use multiple aggregation functions like `MIN(COUNT(ISBN))`.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL and SQL Server are completely different product.  Which one is this?

Comment: Hmm, @KenWhite, if you tell them "MySQL is an Oracle ... product", though not wrong at all, next thing they do is tag [tag:oracle]... ;) It's probably not so important here that Oracle owns it.

Comment: @Barmar how exactly do I fix that issue.

Comment: @stickybit: The important part is that you can't use MS DBMS products with an Oracle DB,just like you can't use Ford parts in a Hyundai auto. The poster needs to figure out what they're asking before they can expect us to help them.

Comment: @KenWhite The point he was trying to make is that the vendor is irrelevant, just the product. MySQL and Oracle are completely different databases, the fact that they both come from Oracle, Inc is irrelevant. Don't confuse them by saying that MySQL is Oracle.

Comment: @Barmar: I specifically mentioned both MySQL and SQL Server in my initial comment, as well as the fact they are different DBMSs. The mention of MS and Oracle were simply details added to the specific DBMSs mentioned (again, MySQL and SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest aggregation functions like `MIN(COUNT(ISBN))`. You need another subquery to get this.

```
Update library 
inner join (
    Select S_Code 
    from Library 
    group by S_Code 
    having count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM library GROUP BY S_Code ORDER BY c LIMIT 1)) s 
on library.S_Code = s.S_Code 
set S_Loc = 'CB-3322';
```